# WPF Change The Visual Template of Specific DataGrid Cells

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, mvvm

I need your help about my issue with datagrid in WPF. In the screenshot below, those highlighted in green, I want to split the cell content into 2. Basically, I would use stackpanel with two textblocks. First textblock has text for example "PORCH M4+ (3)" and the text should be aligned LEFT. Then the second textblock for example has value of "700" and text should be aligned RIGHT. My datasource is DataView and my datagrid has AutoGenerateColumns set to true. The reason why it is set to True because the columns should be dynamic, meaning, column names are not static and they change depending on what you have chosen. I tried modifying the Template on LoadingRow event but it doesn't allow me, because it is sealed. Can anyone help me achieve my desired output?

This is the output datagrid. The highlighted in green are the cells that I want to split. The yellow ones are my keywords. They are fixed and they don't change. This means whenever I see BldgSeq keyword in the itemrow[0] the cells in green will be split.

[image: Datagrid Output Image]

**Datagrid XAML**

```
 <DataGrid  x:Name="dgComparableParcel" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource ="{Binding ComparableParcels, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGeneratingColumn="DgComparableParcel_AutoGeneratingColumn" LoadingRow="DgComparableParcel_LoadingRow" BeginningEdit="DgComparableParcel_BeginningEdit" CellEditEnding="DgComparableParcel_CellEditEnding" FrozenColumnCount="2"  EnableRowVirtualization="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" Grid.Row="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="290" Width="1150" MaxWidth="1150" MaxHeight="290" Padding="0,0,0,0">
 </DataGrid>
```

**DgComparableParcel_LoadingRow event**

```
private void DgComparableParcel_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    dgComparableParcel.Height = 400;
    var row = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
    var currentRowIndex = dgComparableParcel.Items.IndexOf(e.Row.Item);
    if (row != null)
    {
        var itemRow = row.Row;
        var header = itemRow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        if (header.Contains("BldgSeq") || header.Contains("Segments and Adjustments"))
        {
            var stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
            var textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            textBlock.Name = "txt1";
            textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);
            var textBlock1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            textBlock1.Name = "txt2";
            textBlock1.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
            //PORCH M4+ (3) example only
            textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "PORCH M4+ (3)");
            //700 exmple only
            textBlock1.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "700");
            stackPanel.AppendChild(textBlock);
            stackPanel.AppendChild(textBlock1);
            DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
            cellTemplate1.VisualTree = stackPanel;
            //this doesn't allow me to change the visualtree
            //e.Row.Template.VisualTree = stackPanel;

        }
}
}
```

**My datasource**

```
 public DataView ComparableParcels
 {
     get { return _comparableParcels; }
     set { _comparableParcels = value; OnPropertyChanged("ComparableParcels"); }
 }
```